# pyodbc-access column by name

Tags: pyodbc

I have 2 tables with 150 columns and trying to join those tables and fetch the result set one by one and process them:

```
qry = '''select a.*, b.*
         from table_a a
              full outer join table_b b
         where a.id = b.id'''
table_row = conn.execute(qry) #execute method yields a generator
```

Now, I need to access the resultset which is generator and determine the values of each and every column of table-1 & table-2

For example:- if table-1 & table-2 has a column named name, I need to compare it..

How can I access the resultset by columnnname, im using Pyodbc,

ie resultset.table1.name = resultset.table2.name

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the ISO information schema views (I'm using SQL Server in the
   example) to return column names for each table, substituting
   database and schema parameters values as appropriate.
2. Merge the resulting lists into a set containing column names present in both tables.
3. Use this set to build a string representing column names to select from each table, aliasing each column by prefixing with a table name. Defining column aliases will allow you to differentiate columns by table.
4. Execute select query and print values for comparison.

### Code sample

```
# assumes connection, cursor already setup
# build SQL for retrieving column names
sql = '''SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN
         WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = ? AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?
               AND TABLE_NAME = ?'''

# get column names from table_a
rows = cursor.execute(sql, ('database', 'schema', 'table_a')).fetchall()
table_a_columns = [column[0] for column in rows]

# get column names from table_b
rows = cursor_b.execute(sql, ('database', 'schema', 'table_b')).fetchall()
table_b_columns = [column[0] for column in rows]

# get unique matching columns from lists
matches = set(table_a_columns).intersection(table_b_columns)

# get string of column names to use in query, setting column alias prefixed with
# table name for each column
column_alias = 'a.{0} as a_{0}, b.{0} as b_{0}'
columns = ', '.join([column_alias.format(column) for column in matches])
sql = 'SELECT {} FROM table_a a FULL OUTER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id'
sql = sql.format(columns)

# print values to compare
for row in cursor.execute(sql):
    print row
```

There's probably a less complicated way, but it's eluding me.